# Operator '!=' cannot be applied

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i try to create this check condition

if (dtimg != "")

{
// 
}

it show following error

Error 4 Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.DataTable' and 'string' E:\user\Mohsin.Malik\Project\FlagProperties\code\FlagProperties\Pages\FraturePropertyDetail.aspx.cs 104 13 http://localhost/FlagProperties/

Comment: This isn't a question.  It's a statement.  Sounds like your compiler's working great.

Answer (score 3):

dtimg is a DataTable... and "" is a String.

You can't compare a DataTable with string. Maybe you want to check for null?

if (dtimg != null)
{
// do something
}

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are comparing a DataTable to a string, which is illegal in most countries.

What are you trying to do? Null check? In that case, you should use

`if (dtimg != null)`

Comment: when need to check on datatable or dataset then that condition not work it just check for string type for datatable and dataset can be use following condition
 if (dtimg != null && dtimg.Rows.Count > 0){} ....i try this and it works

Comment: Well, then, there you go! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You got the answer right there:

> Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.DataTable' and 'string'